# jQuery - How to reset specific fields value

Tags: jquery, field, reset, siblings

i want to reset value from specific input file

how it can be done if i have structure code like this....

```
<div id="row_btnbar1" class="buttonbar">
    <div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <output id="show_img1"></output>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <input type="file" id="files1" name="files[]"/>
            <button id="reset1" type="reset" class="reset">
                <span>Reset</span>
            </button>
            <span class="process"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="row_btnbar2" class="buttonbar">
    // #files2, #reset2
</div>
<div id="row_btnbar3" class="buttonbar">
    // #files3, #reset3 
</div>
<div id="row_btnbar4" class="buttonbar">
    // #files4, #reset4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTML file input can't be cleared by normal means (i.e. setting the value to null or an empty string), but because of browser security restrictions, most browsers don't allow this. In many browsers, setting a null value attribute either will have no effect or cause an error. Instead, create a new element that clones the old element and swap the two.

Read : [How to clear HTML file inputs](http://aspnetupload.com/Clear-HTML-File-Input.aspx)

---

> Trick:- You have to create new input type file and replace it with old one.

---

**js**

```
function clearFileInput() {
    var oldInput = document.getElementById("files1");
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "file";
    newInput.id = oldInput.id;
    newInput.name = oldInput.name;
    newInput.className = oldInput.className;
    newInput.style.cssText = oldInput.style.cssText;
    // copy any other relevant attributes 
    oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, oldInput);
}
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7EVS4/)</kbd>

---

Updated after OP's comment

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7EVS4/2)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function clearFileInput(el) {
        var oldInput = document.getElementById(el);
        var newInput = document.createElement("input");
        newInput.type = "file";
        newInput.id = oldInput.id;
        newInput.name = oldInput.name;
        newInput.className = oldInput.className;
        newInput.style.cssText = oldInput.style.cssText;
        // copy any other relevant attributes 
        oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(newInput, oldInput);
    }
    $('.reset').click(function () {
        clearFileInput($(this).prev('input[type="file"]').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: this is full code preview http://jsfiddle.net/7EVS4/1/, i want to reset only current input file being filled.

Comment: @gierg Welocme Happy to help :)

Comment: @thusar-gupta: Today I tried again to test, but i got an error, "TypeError: oldInput is null". why did it happen? do i have to make an additional function to handle null elements?